# Is any C++ compiler able to optimize lround(pow(sqrt(i), 2)) replacing it with i, now or in the near future?

Tags: c++, optimization

In some cases of microbenchmarking, static code analyzer is smart enough to elide multiple function calls with the same argument values, rendering measurement useless. Benchmarking function `f` with code like this:

```
long s = 0;
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  startTimer();
  s += f(M);
  stopTimer();
}
...
cout << s;
```

can be defeated by optimizer. I wonder, if current or near future optimizer technology is smart enough to defeat this version:

```
long s = 0;
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  long m = lround(pow(sqrt(i), 2))/i*M;
  startTimer();
  s += f(m);
  stopTimer();
}
...
cout << s;
```

Comment: "Any" compiler? Then the answer is no, because without optimizataion at all, it´s still C++ (and there are such things). Concerning your compiler, just look to the asm output...

Comment: Why not use a bit of algerbra?

Comment: This is not unthinkable, compilers could come enhanced with powerful algebraic systems. Anyway, if such things arose, I'd prefer to be told by the compiler what transformations it applied.

Comment: @YvesDaoust compilers do tell you, just look at the assembly listing. Anyways, the rest is under the "As-If"-rule and transformations should not concern you, as the programmer. The standard is not in the business of specifying the code generation. It just defines the ***correct*** behaviour of the generated code. Timing, though, is unspecified here.

Answer (score 4):

Answer you title question:

> Is any C++ compiler able to optimize lround(pow(sqrt(i), 2)) replacing it with i, now or in the near future?

yes, for statically known arguments: see it **[Live On Godbolt](http://goo.gl/KMLRSP)**

All of the code in that sample program got compiled down to a single constant value! And, best of all, that's with ***optimizations disabled***: `g++-4.8 -O0` :)

```
#include <cmath>
constexpr int N = 100;
constexpr double M = 1.0;
constexpr int i = 4;

static constexpr double foo1(int i) { return sqrt(i); }
static constexpr auto f1 = foo1(4);

static constexpr double foo2(int i) { return pow(sqrt(i), 2); }
static constexpr auto f2 = foo2(4);

static constexpr double foo3(int i) { return pow(sqrt(i), 2)/i*M; }
static constexpr auto f3 = foo3(4);

static constexpr long foo4(int i) { return pow(sqrt(i), 2)/i*M; }
static constexpr auto f4 = foo4(4);

#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("f1 + f2 + f3 + f4: %f\n", f1 + f2 + f2 + f3);
}
```

Get's compiled into a single, statically known constant:

```
.LC1:
    .string "f1 + f2 + f3 + f4: %f\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB225:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movabsq $4622382067542392832, %rax
    vmovd   %rax, %xmm0
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
```

Voila. That's because the GNU standard library has `constexpr` versions of the math functions (except the `lround`) in C++11 mode.

It's entirely thinkable that the compiler unrolls a loop like

```
for (int i; i<5; ++i) 
    s += foo(i);
```

into

```
s += foo(1);
s += foo(2);
s += foo(3);
s += foo(4);
```

Though I haven't checked that yet.

Comment: Your example is not quite the same as my use case. `constexpr` can't be applied to the expression `lround(pow(sqrt(i), 2))/i*M` inside a loop, when `N` is large, as it will always be for benchmarking.

Comment: Whether N is large is irrelevant. A compiler can decide that it can precalculate the whole shebang. The `lround` is currently what thwarts the complete constexpr-ification. Further more, I specified which part of the question I answered. I do realize there's more context, but I thought that this was informative enough on it's own, and a surprise to many :)

Comment: Well, you explicitly directed the compiler to evaluate these expressions at compile time by using `consexpr`. I'm sure that for N = 1000000, compiler will not unroll my loop and calculate 1M expressions. Having said that, your example still shows an interesting angle, thanks.

Comment: @PaulJurczak The point is "Yes, any C++ compiler is able to optimize static_cast<long>((pow(sqrt(i), 2))/i*M) replacing it with <constant>". And, no, I didn't actually do much special, GNU stdlib **already** defines `pow` and `sqrt` as constexpr. Will simplify the code to reduce confusion

Comment: @PaulJurczak Now, this isn't that far-fetched, agreed? **[It compiles at -O1 now](http://goo.gl/KOYHZU)**

Comment: `It compiles at -O1 now`, but it looses its magic, if the loop has more than one iteration ;-(

Comment: @PaulJurczak I know. I'll repeat once more: _I'm aware of the limitations_ and I answered a specific part of the question. I hope it's somehow informative. (I was just pointing out I didn't didn't jump through hoops to get this behaviour, as you were claiming in your previous comment). Cheers

Comment: I must start to formulate my questions more carefully. I just noticed that you did in fact answer my title question accurately :-) Unfortunately, I was looking for slightly different context (as described in the body of my post).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the optimiser must be taught the semantics of library functions, which is hard and time consuming.

Then again IEEE754 math is tricky.

Comment: Do you know of any existing optimizer doing this sort of analysis?

Comment: +1 for IEEE 754 math is tricky. Optimizers often leave the most of FP expressions alone because many "innocent" changes can have subtle but important effects.

Comment: Can't remember right off the top of my head, there was some research project that wanted to reason about the semantics of library functions, but it was more for code analysis purposes than optimization. The researchers mentioned that it could be used in optimizers also, but I forgot the name. Sorry.

Comment: @MatteoItalia _Optimizers often leave the most of FP expressions alone_ that's exactly what I was hoping for. They wouldn't dare to risk simplifying it :-)

Comment: @Paul They don't need to simplify anything to optimize it for statically known arguments, though. They can just perform the conforming implementation at compile-time and insert the result, as you can see in my answer already happens.

Answer (score 1):

What about declaring `volatile long m= M;` instead ?

Comment: I don't see how this addresses my question. Do you think that `volatile long m = lround(pow(sqrt(i), 2))/i*M;` makes it easier for optimizer to replace it with `long m = M;`?

Comment: A better approach to achieve your goal, which is to inhibit optimizing away the function calls.

Comment: I see, calling `f(m)`, where `m` is `volatile`. Much simpler, thank you.